# In Angualrjs i18n-content which have link with ng-click does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, sitecore

This link does work

```
<a ng-click="TermsAndConditionsModal('TermsAndConditionsHTML')">Terms and conditions</a>
```

But when render the same content from sitecore, link does not work and does not display any error in browser console

```
<a ng-click="TermsAndConditionsModal('TermsAndConditionsHTML')">Terms and conditions</a>
```

I am using the angularjs 1.6

Text in html template

```
<div class="col" i18n-content="sitecoreContent"></div>
```

Comment: Use debugger and see if the function is being called or not?

Comment: Some reason if i click on link render directly does work and trigger the function. But same text link if I render through the sitecore i18n-content link does not work. click does not call the function. Even in both the case html in same.